# Scanner no reconoce entradas

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en Java. no logro que reconozca los ingresos que hago. Donde esta el error?

```js
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  Punto p = new Punto();
  String direccion = "";
  int pasos = 0;
  String salir = "";

  System.out.println("Hacia donde desea mover el punto\n");
  do {
    System.out.println("Derecha \"D\": \n" +
      "Izquierda \"I\": \n" +
      "Arriba \"A\": \n" +
      "Abajo \"B\": ");
    direccion = sc.next();

    System.out.println("Ingrese cantidad de pasos: ");
    pasos = sc.nextInt();

    if (direccion == "D") {
      p.SetX(pasos);
    } else if (direccion == "I") {
      p.SetX(-pasos);
    } else if (direccion == "A") {
      p.SetY(pasos);
    } else if (direccion == "B") {
      p.SetY(-pasos);
    }
    int CoordX = p.GetX();
    int CoordY = p.GetY();
    System.out.println("Posicion actual: (" + CoordX + " , " + CoordY + ")");
    System.out.println("Presione \"S\" para salir.");
    salir = sc.next();
  } while (salir != "S");
}
```

Aclaro que hice el importe correspondiente a scanner. La clase punto no la muestro porque Netbean no me marca ningun error alli.
Cuando lo ejecuto, ingreso algún valor, ej: D  y 7, con esto debería mostrar la posición (7,0), pero muestra (0,0). Además tampoco me reconoce la letra S, para salir.

Answer (score 1):

El error está en la manera que compruebas la cadena de caracteres leída, que tiene varias partes para entenderse bien.

Para empezar, Java es un lenguaje orientado a objetos, lo que quiere decir que todo aquí son objetos. Pero además, en java, cada objeto tiene un identificador de objeto (`OID`). Así, dos objetos con el mismo contenido, pero ocupando dos direcciones de memoria (a través de la JVM) tendrán cada uno un `OID` único.

Por otro lado, tenemos que, si bien todo en Java son objetos, también tenemos tipos primitivos muy básicos, que pueden ser tratados como objetos, o no.
Entre estos, destacan los tipos básicos de cualquier lenguaje, como los enteros (`int`), booleanos (`boolean`), flotantes de simple (`float`) y doble (`double`) precisión, así como otros típicos.

Ahora bien, el operador de igualdad (`==`) lo que hace es: si las dos variables son de tipo primitivo, comprueba si los valores coinciden, mientras que si las dos variables son objetos de una clase, compara si sus `OID` son iguales, es decir, si se trata del mismo objeto físico.

Por último, `String` es una clase de Java, no un tipo primitivo. Cuando crees un objeto de clase `String`, este objeto tendrá un `OID` único, así como la cadena de caracteres propiamente dicha.

Ahora bien, si creas dos cadenas con el mismo contenido, tendrán dos `OID` diferentes, por lo que la comparación siempre da `false`, lo que quiere decir simplemente que tienen identificadores distintos, aunque su contenido puede ser el mismo o no.

Además, cuando creas un literal cadena, del tipo `"Hola"`, lo que ocurre es que se crea un objeto `String` con ese contenido y un identificador único, y las variables a las que asignes ese literal solo harán referencia al identificador del objeto que contiene el literal.

Sin embargo, cuando lees una cadena por consola, se crea un objeto nuevo con un identificador único, independientemente del contenido.

Así, si lees una cadena en una variable y la comparas con un literal, sus identificadores van a ser diferentes siempre.

Como apunte final, la igualdad entre objetos no se comprueba con el operador `==`, sino mediante el método `equals`, por lo que tu código debería ser así:

```
if (direccion.equals("D")) p.setX(pasos);
else if (direccion.equals("I")) p.setX(-pasos);
else if (direccion.equals("A")) p.setY(pasos);
else if (direccion.equals("B")) p.setY(-pasos);
else /* Tratar los demás casos */;
```

Como habrás notado, no he escrito `SetX`, sino `setX`. Recuerda que, por convención, métodos y atributos comienzan siempre por minúscula. Solo los nombres de las clases deben empezar con mayúscula, como el caso de `String`, cuyo nombre ya nos indica que se trata de una clase.

Comment: Muchas gracias Eequiis. Excelente tu explicación. No se si puedo darte puntaje o marcar tu respuesta como correcta. si me indicas como hacerlo, lo hago con gusto.